# How can I access implicit "implicit" i.e. def a[A :B] or def a[A <% B]?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

for example I need to access manifest in function `def a[A:ClassManifest]` to get erasure class. I can use Predef.implicitly function but in that case my code will be as long as if I use full form `def a[A](implicit b:ClassManifest[A])`.
So is there are convenient generated names for those implicit arguments?

Comment: You can always declare a method with a smaller name, but you should _not_ depend on magic names generated by Scalac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three predefined methods in `Predef` that will do it for `Manifest`s, `ClassManifest`s and `OptManifest`s: `manifest[T]`, `classManifest[T]` and `optManifest[T]`, respectively. You can write your own such “implicit getters” for other type classes according to the same pattern. Here is for instance `manifest[T]`:

```
def manifest[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]) = m
```

So here's how you could write your own:

```
trait UsefulTypeclass[A] {
  def info = 42 // sample method
}

// the “implicit getter”
def usefulTypeclass[A](implicit tc: UsefulTypeclass[A]) = tc

// a method that uses the implicit getter
def foo[A: UsefulTypeclass] =
  usefulTypeclass[A].info
```

Comment: As a neat trick: if you name the implicit getter "apply" and put it on UsefulTypeclass's companion object, you can use "UsefulTypeclass[T]" as a value representing the instance of the typeclass for T without having to import anything more than the typeclass itself.

Comment: @RM Nice trick. I guess it'd have to be `UsefulTypeclass[T]()` (with the extra `()`) then.

Comment: Actually it doesn't need the parens.  If you have (pardon the lack of formatting) object TC { def apply[T](implicit x: TC[T]) = x } you can literally invoke it with just "TC[SomeClass]" because "apply" is being defined as a parameterless method with an implicit parameter list, and the [SomeClass] disambiguates it from just a reference to the TC object.  It desugars to TC.apply[SomeClass](theImplicitValue)

Answer (score 0):

scalap to the rescue!

I took this code:

```
object TestThing extends App {
  def one { println("one") }
  def two[T] { println("two") }
  def three[T : Manifest] { println("three") }
  def four[T: Manifest, U : Manifest] { println("four") }
}
```

and ran it through scalap.  Here's what I got:

```
object TestThing extends java.lang.Object with scala.App with scala.ScalaObject {
  def this() = { /* compiled code */ }
  def one : scala.Unit = { /* compiled code */ }
  def two[T] : scala.Unit = { /* compiled code */ }
  def three[T](implicit evidence$1 : scala.Predef.Manifest[T]) : scala.Unit = { /* compiled code */ }
  def four[T, U](implicit evidence$2 : scala.Predef.Manifest[T], evidence$3 : scala.Predef.Manifest[U]) : scala.Unit = { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

As you can see, the first implicit Manifest is called `evidence$1`.  The second and third—**though in a different scope!**—are called `evidence$2` and `evidence$3`.  So... that's how you make reference to Manifests.

Despite that, though, it seems a bit scary to me that removing a Manifest that is higher up in the class will change the name of a Manifest that is located lower in the file.  Similarly, it also doesn't help that the IntelliJ Scala plugin's syntax highlighting seems to think that the Manifest variables in scope in `four()` are `evidence$1` and `evidence$2`, and it doesn't think that `evidence$3` is a valid variable there (even though it is, and `evidence$1` is not).  Overall, maybe these things should be heeded as warning signs about playing with implicit Manifest variables?

Comment: Surely those names should be an internal implementation detail and not relied on!

Comment: That is why you use `implicitly`... trying to use `evidence$1` etc in your code won't compile.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Actually, it does compile... scarily enough.